# How can I make preg_replace only replace the first of *each* character matched?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

For example, the following code wraps each matching character with an `<i>` tag.

```
echo preg_replace('/[aeiou]/', '<i>$0</i>', 'alphabet');
// result: <i>a</i>lph<i>a</i>b<i>e</i>t
```

But I'd like it to only replace each character once.

I'm looking for a result like `<i>a</i>lphab<i>e</i>t`, where the second `a` makes it through without a tag because the search string only has one `a`.

Can you help?  Is this possible without of iterating through each character in an foreach loop?

The answer should also allow for two or more of the same characters, each only to be used once.  For example, if I were searching for `aaeioo` in the string `alphabetsoupisgood`, it should match both of the `a`'s but only two of the three `o`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a letter to be replaced only once then following regex should work:

```
echo preg_replace('/([aeiou])(?!.+?\\1)/', '<i>$1</i>', 'alphabet');
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
alph<i>a</i>b<i>e</i>t
```

**PS:** Note that it replaces last occurrence of a letter instead of the first one.

**EDIT:**

Following would produce the same output as expected by the OP (thanks to @AntonyHatchkins):

```
echo strrev(preg_replace
        ('/([aeiou])(?!.+?\\1)/', strrev('<i>1$</i>'), strrev('alphabet')))."\n";
```

**EDIT 2:**

Upon OP's comment:

`Can you help me allow more than one a then? How can I match 2, but not 3 a's`

I am posting this answer:

```
echo strrev(preg_replace('/([aeiou])(?!(.+?\\1){2})/', 
            strrev('<i>1$</i>'), strrev('alphabetax'))) . "\n";
```

**EDIT 3:**

Upon another of OP's comment:

`that will allow duplicates for all characters in the string, not just 2 a's & 1 e`

I am posting this answer:

```
echo strrev(preg_replace(array('/(a)(?!(.+?\\1){2})/', 
  '/(?<!>)([eiou])(?!.+?\\1)/'), 
  array(strrev('<i>1$</i>'), strrev('<i>1$</i>')), strrev('alphabetaxen')))."\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<i>a</i>lph<i>a</i>b<i>e</i>taxen
```

**Note: I believe original problem has already changed so many times so please don't add further complexity in this problem. You're free to post another question if you have different queries.**

Comment: `strrev(preg_replace('/([aeiou])(?!.+?\\1)/', '<i>$1</i>', strrev('alphabet'))` will make it the first one

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: Good point, but it gives this output `t<i>e</i>bahpl<i>a</i>`

Comment: Note the second strrev: `echo strrev(preg_replace('/([aeiou])(?!.+?\\1)/', strrev('<i>1$</i>'), strrev('alphabet')));`  gives `<i>a</i>lphab<i>e</i>t`

Comment: This works if there are no duplicate characters in the search string.  But it fails if the search string is `aa`. See http://codepad.org/iHPpgfl7

Comment: @Ryan: Your regex has `[aaiou]` which is equivalent of `[aiou]` and since out of these 4 chars `aiou` only `a` is found in `alphabet` that's why you are getting this result: `<i>a</i>lphabet`

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Can you help me allow more than one `a` then?  How can I match 2, but not 3 `a`'s?

Comment: It might be possible but IMHO that changes the nature of this problem completely. I would request you to post that as a separate question and get better answers there.

Comment: @Ryan: I have posted an answer here in `EDIT 2` section above that will allow 2 a's but not 3.

Comment: I see, but then that will allow duplicates for all characters in the string, not just 2 a's and 1 e.  Looks like my loop through the characters will have to do.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Ryan: Please check **EDIT 3:** for solution to the latest problem you've posted.

Comment: I think this works.  I can separate the search string into counts and preg_replace that way.  I appreciate the effort.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php, you can specify an additional parameter that limits the amount of replaces done.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't originally get your question. In that case, it's not possible. Due to the nature of Regex, it's not aware of the amount of replacements it has made. I might be wrong though, but I doubt that a regular expression exists that only makes one replacement per character.

Your best bet would be to make 5 calls, one each per character. Something like this:

```
$res = preg_replace('/a/', '<i>$0</i>', 'alphabet', 1);
$res = preg_replace('/e/', '<i>$0</i>', 'alphabet', 1);
$res = preg_replace('/i/', '<i>$0</i>', 'alphabet', 1);
$res = preg_replace('/o/', '<i>$0</i>', 'alphabet', 1);
$res = preg_replace('/u/', '<i>$0</i>', 'alphabet', 1);

echo $res;
```

Cheers

Comment: Close, but this method doesn't allow the preg_replace to continue to replace the `e` at the end.  The result is only `lphabet` and not `lphabt`.

Comment: Not quite.  I was optimistic at first, but the subsequent preg_replaces end up including the tags as well.  See http://codepad.org/dF4d3Qvn

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo preg_replace('/[aeiou]/', ' ', 'alphabet', 1);
```

Sorry i ansered before you edited your question

How about this.

```
$word = "alphabet";

$replace = array('a','e','i','o','u');
$with = array('','','','','');

echo str_replace($replace,$with,$word); //lphbt
```

Comment: Close, but it doesn't allow the preg_replace to continue to replace the `e` at the end.  The result is only `lphabet` and not `lphabt`.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but here's an approach.

```
echo 
preg_replace('/a/','<i>$0</i>',
preg_replace('/e/','<i>$0</i>',
preg_replace('/i/','<i>$0</i>',
preg_replace('/o/','<i>$0</i>',
preg_replace('/u/','<i>$0</i>','alphabet',
1),1),1),1),1);
```

Comment: This is very close, but fails if there are more than one of the same characters in the search string.  See http://codepad.org/X14ESSUL

Comment: Just use `'~(?<!<i>)YOUR_LETTER_HERE(?!</i>)~'` instead of `'/YOUR_LETTER_HERE/'` in each pattern.

Comment: Extra information: first part in pattern says "not preceded by `<i>`" and the last part says "not followed by `</i>`".

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function so I'm posting this as a brand new answer.

```
function replace_first($matches) {
    static $used = array();
    $key = $matches[0];
    if (in_array($key,$used)) return $key;
    $used[] = $key;
    return '<i>' . $key . '</i>';
}

$str = preg_replace_callback('/[aeiou]/','replace_first','alphabet');
echo $str;
```

will output `<i>a</i>lphab<i>e</i>t`

Comment: Yes, but if the search string is `aa` it will miss the second `a` in alphabet.  See http://codepad.org/Via4Hhp9

Comment: Of course, because that's what you asked, and regular expression character ranges such as `/[abc]/` and `/[aaaaaaaabc]/` are the same. You might want to change your method if that's what you're willing to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

The best I could do is loop through each character. (I try to avoid loops whenever possible)  I wish there was a cleaner way, but this will do for now.

```
$word = 'alphabetsoupisgood';
$match = 'aaeou';
$wordArr = str_split($word);
$matchArr = str_split($capitals);

foreach ($matchArr as $c) {
    $key = array_search($c, $wordArr);
    if ($key !== false) {
        $wordArr[$key] = strtoupper($c);
    }
}

foreach ($wordArr as $k => $c) {
    if (ctype_upper($c)) {
        $wordArr[$k] = '<i>' . strtolower($c) . '</i>';
    }
}
$word = implode('',$wordArr);
echo $word;
```

Here it is in codepad but they're running some super old version of PHP so `ctype_upper` isn't enabled... http://codepad.org/UoLWcK2S

If anyone can provide a cleaner answer using preg_replace I'd gladly mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I share your feelings. For some reason downvoters don't tend to spend anytime explaining why :/